# For AWS SFN Fail State, what is Cause length limit?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

[The documentation page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-fail-state.html) says that there are **Cause** and **CausePath** fields available that can be used for describing the actual cause of the SFN state machine run failure.

**What would be the maximum amount of characters that I can put there?**

I would like to pass as much information as possible to simplify issue investigation and being able to preserve such errors in the SFN run history

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AWS [quota](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/limits-overview.html#service-limits-task-executions) on payload size applies to the whole thing, not to a field.  The "maximum input or output size for a task, state, or execution" is "256 KB of data as a UTF-8 encoded string".

How many characters fit into the 256 KB depends on the UTF-8 encodings.